# WCF Service invoked from SQL Server Stored Procedure through HTTPS

Tags: sql-server, wcf, https

I am calling one WCF service from SQL Server stored procedure through HTTPS service and getting below error:

> The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect.

The service invocation is successful when the service is being called through HTTP but the issue is coming while calling it through HTTPS.

The same WCF service invocation through HTTPS is successful when I call it via SOAP UI. But when the service is getting called from SQL Server Stored Prcoedure then the issue appears through HTTPS.

Comment: Is the sql server local or hosted on another server?

Comment: Hi Popo,SQL Server is hosted on another server. but I have installed the client certificate on that machine also where SQL server is installed.

Comment: I got it worked now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the error is about the "certificate authority", that is the issuer of the server certificate. Probably you use self-signed certificates. In this case you need to install the CA certificate on the client machine too, in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". Otherwise the client will fail to validate the server certificate exactly because it cannot validate its issuer (the certificate authority).

Comment: So, you have installed the CA certificate (in addition to the server certificate) on the host of SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, even after that it didn't work. Actually I was not specifying explicitly the certificate name in the stored procedure implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All, I got it working. Actually the certificate name need to be explicitly specified in the stored procedure as below which was missing in my implementation.

```
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @objectID,
           'setOption',
           NULL,
           3,
           'LOCAL_MACHINE\My\'Certificate Name';
```

Below is the complete stored procedure implementation to call a web service from the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_INT_SendHttpRequest]
    @URI          VARCHAR(2000) = '',
    @methodName   VARCHAR(50)   = '',
    @requestBody  VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @SoapAction   VARCHAR(255),
    @UserName     NVARCHAR(100), -- Domain\UserName or UserName 
    @Password     NVARCHAR(100),
    @responseText VARCHAR(8000) OUTPUT
AS
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       IF @methodName = ''
          BEGIN
             SELECT FailPoint = 'Method Name must be set';
             RETURN;
          END;
       SET @responseText = 'FAILED';
       DECLARE @objectID INT;
       DECLARE @hResult INT;
       DECLARE @source VARCHAR(255), @desc VARCHAR(255);
       EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate
           'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP',
           @objectID OUT;
       IF @hResult <> 0
          BEGIN
             EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
                 @objectID,
                 @source OUT,
                 @desc OUT;
             SELECT hResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @hResult),
                   source = @source,
                   description = @desc,
                   FailPoint = 'Create failed',
                   MedthodName = @methodName;
             GOTO destroy;
             RETURN;
          END;
       EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @objectID,
           'setOption',
           NULL,
           3,
           'LOCAL_MACHINE\My\ClientSignedByDevCA';
       IF @hResult <> 0
          BEGIN
             EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
                 @objectID,
                 @source OUT,
                 @desc OUT;
             SELECT hResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @hResult),
                   source = @source,
                   description = @desc,
                   FailPoint = 'Set Certificate failed',
                   MedthodName = @methodName;
             GOTO destroy;
             RETURN;
          END;

-- open the destination URI with Specified method 
       EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @objectID,
           'open',
           NULL,
           @methodName,
           @URI,
           'false',
           @UserName,
           @Password;
       IF @hResult <> 0
          BEGIN
             EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
                 @objectID,
                 @source OUT,
                 @desc OUT;
             SELECT hResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @hResult),
                   source = @source,
                   description = @desc,
                   FailPoint = 'Open failed',
                   MedthodName = @methodName;
             GOTO destroy;
             RETURN;
          END;
-- set request headers 
       EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @objectID,
           'setRequestHeader',
           NULL,
           'Content-Type',
           'text/xml;charset=UTF-8';
       IF @hResult <> 0
          BEGIN
             EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
                 @objectID,
                 @source OUT,
                 @desc OUT;
             SELECT hResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @hResult),
                   source = @source,
                   description = @desc,
                   FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed',
                   MedthodName = @methodName;
             GOTO destroy;
             RETURN;
          END;
-- set soap action 
       EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @objectID,
           'setRequestHeader',
           NULL,
           'SOAPAction',
           @SoapAction;
       IF @hResult <> 0
          BEGIN
             EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
                 @objectID,
                 @source OUT,
                 @desc OUT;
             SELECT hResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @hResult),
                   source = @source,
                   description = @desc,
                   FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed',
                   MedthodName = @methodName;
             GOTO destroy;
             RETURN;
          END;
       DECLARE @len INT;
       SET @len = LEN(@requestBody);
       EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @objectID,
           'setRequestHeader',
           NULL,
           'Content-Length',
           @len;
       IF @hResult <> 0
          BEGIN
             EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
                 @objectID,
                 @source OUT,
                 @desc OUT;
             SELECT hResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @hResult),
                   source = @source,
                   description = @desc,
                   FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed',
                   MedthodName = @methodName;
             GOTO destroy;
             RETURN;
          END;
       EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @objectID,
           'send',
           NULL,
           @requestBody;
       IF @hResult <> 0
          BEGIN
             EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
                 @objectID,
                 @source OUT,
                 @desc OUT;
             SELECT hResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @hResult),
                   source = @source,
                   description = @desc,
                   FailPoint = 'Send failed',
                   MedthodName = @methodName;
             GOTO destroy;
             RETURN;
          END;
       DECLARE @statusText VARCHAR(1000), @status VARCHAR(1000); 
-- Get status text 
       EXEC sp_OAGetProperty
           @objectID,
           'StatusText',
           @statusText OUT;
       EXEC sp_OAGetProperty
           @objectID,
           'Status',
           @status OUT;
       SELECT @status,
            @statusText,
            @methodName; 
-- Get response text 
       EXEC sp_OAGetProperty
           @objectID,
           'responseText',
           @responseText OUT;
       IF @hResult <> 0
          BEGIN
             EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
                 @objectID,
                 @source OUT,
                 @desc OUT;
             SELECT hResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @hResult),
                   source = @source,
                   description = @desc,
                   FailPoint = 'ResponseText failed',
                   MedthodName = @methodName;
             GOTO destroy;
             RETURN;
          END;
       destroy:
       EXEC sp_OADestroy
           @objectID;
       SET @responseText = 'SUCCESS'
       SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    END;
```

Comment: Option 3 is named SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT. It should be used when the certificate is not in the local machine store, or when there are multiple certificates. +1 for the detailed stored procedure. Could you check if the certificate is in 'Local machine' and not (maybe) in 'Personal' store?

Comment: I have to use it even though the certificate as in the personal store of my local machine. Probably because , there are multiple certificates in the personal store.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to grant read access to the file that contains the private key to the account that WCF is running under. There are step by step instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-make-x-509-certificates-accessible-to-wcf